# api3.geo.admin.ch v 3.6.0 OpenLayers 3 DragBox not displaying on map when using firefox ( it works fine on chrome and IE edge)

Tags: openlayers-3

Below code works on chrome and IE without any issue but not in Firefox.

it seems that map.addInteraction(dragBox) is not taking effect when using Firefox.
Any help is appreciated .

```
var selectionBoxStyle =  new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(80, 118, 141, 0.4)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#044E7D',
        width:2
    })
});
var dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
    condition: ol.events.condition.always,
    style: olStylesFactory.selectionBoxStyle
});
map.addInteraction(dragBox);
```

Comment: It may be related to this issue https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/1583  The DragBox was changed in version 3.11.0 because of it.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, the issue is only visible on Firefox